# Passing some id from Dropzone using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm having a Modal to upload images into the gallery like this:

```
<div id="imagesModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="imagesForm" id="addImages" class="form-horizontal dropzone" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('images.add') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('POST') }}
            </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and here's my jquery script:

```
$( "#addImages" ).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                save_method = 'add';
                $('input[name=_method]').val('POST');
                $('#imagesModal').modal("show");
                $('#imagesForm')[0].reset();
                $('.modal-title').text('Add Images')
            });

            Dropzone.options.addImages = {
                paramName: "images", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
                maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            };

and i already add the route and the function

   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::find($request->id);
        $path = 'public'.'/'.str_slug($gallery->name);

        foreach ($request->images as $file) {
            $image = new Image();
            $image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
            $image->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->extension = $file->extension();
            $image->size = $file->getClientSize();
            $image->save();

            // Or any custom name as the third argument
            Storage::putFileAs($path, $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        }

    }
```

My problem is i don't know how i can pass the gallery id so i can access it into the function? I have some idea to put it on data-gallery-id in the button, but how can pass that data so it's going to be sent with the images?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can send along with images object. But you can do this way instead. You can create one input type hidden to store the image gallery id in your form ex: 
After you submit the form you can get the $request->id in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

As per their [Documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-params)

> `params`: Can be an object of additional parameters to transfer to the server, or a Function that gets invoked with the files, xhr and, if it's a chunked upload, chunk arguments. In case of a function, this needs to return a map.
>   The default implementation does nothing for normal uploads, but adds relevant information for chunked uploads.

So you could modify your dropzone configuration as

```
Dropzone.options.addImages = {
    paramName: "images", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB

    // Whether to send multiple files in one request. 
    // If this it set to true, then the fallback file input element will 
    // have the multiple attribute as well.
    uploadMultiple: TRUE,

    params: {
        'gallery_id' : 1 // Your gallery Id
    }
};
```

This is the same as adding hidden input fields in the form element.

Comment: ok i will give it try, but i think i have to change my code. since using same id in the button is wrong. i have to figure it out first since the button is in foreach so it has the same id.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the dropzone event method which is called  before each file is sent this method have 3 parameters file: for the file that will be sent, xhr for data transfer, and formData which will contain your data

in your case you have to do :

```
Dropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
formData.append('gallery_id',  put_here_your_id )

}
```

and in the laravel controller you can read your id :

```
$request->galery_id
```